# Upload de Fotos Múltiplo JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2, upload, multiple-file-upload

Estou precisando fazer uma tela de cadastro, onde o usuário poderá escolher até 5 fotos para salvar.

Estou usando JSF 2.2 gostaria de saber a melhor maneira para isso, sem usar `primefaces` ou `richfaces`, usando um componente tipo http://www.plupload.com/examples/ui , tentei usar `Serlvet`, porém não consigo passar as imagens para o managedbean.

O ideal é que as fotos fossem salvas ao submeter a página.

Alguém tem uma solução?

Comment: Você poderia postar o que já tem feito até o momento? tais como `.xhtml` e seu `ManagedBean` ?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver esse problema @FelipeSousa?